# drawRect() is not called at all in Cocoa app

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm very new in programming OS X Cocoa applications. So please be sympathetic. I want to make an application simple and I have blocked myself to drawing images in the application.

This code should draw multiple images and change the arrangement when resize or maximize the window app.

```
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#ifndef NSWindowStyleMaskTitled
#define NSWindowStyleMaskTitled NSTitledWindowMask
#define NSWindowStyleMaskClosable NSClosableWindowMask
#define NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable NSMiniaturizableWindowMask
#define NSWindowStyleMaskResizable NSResizableWindowMask
#define NSEventMaskAny NSAnyEventMask
#endif

@interface Window : NSWindow {
    NSTimer* mTimer;
}
- (instancetype)init;
- (BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder;
- (BOOL) acceptsFirstMouse: (NSEvent*) pEvent;
- (void) viewDidMoveToWindow;
- (void) drawRect: (NSRect) rect;
- (void) onTimer: (NSTimer*) pTimer;
- (void) getMouseXY: (NSEvent*) pEvent x: (int*) pX y: (int*) pY;
- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)event;
- (void) mouseUp: (NSEvent*) event;
- (void) mouseDragged: (NSEvent*) event;
- (void) rightMouseDown: (NSEvent*) event;
- (void) rightMouseUp: (NSEvent*) event;
- (NSDragOperation) draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender;
- (BOOL) performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender;
- (void) windowDidResize:(NSNotification*)notification;
- (void) windowDidMiniaturize:(NSNotification*)sender;
- (void) windowDidDeMiniaturize:(NSNotification*)sender;
- (BOOL) windowShouldClose:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation Window
- (instancetype)init {
    
    mTimer = 0;
    double sec = 1.0 / 24;
    mTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:sec target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: mTimer forMode: (NSString*) kCFRunLoopCommonModes];
    [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidResize:) name:NSWindowDidResizeNotification object:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidMiniaturize:) name:NSWindowDidMiniaturizeNotification object:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidDeMiniaturize:) name:NSWindowDidDeminiaturizeNotification object:self];

    
    [super initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 500, 300) styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
  [self setTitle:@"Hello world"];
  [self center];
    
    [self setOpaque:NO];
    [self setHasShadow:YES];
    //[self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor grayColor]];
    
  [self setIsVisible:YES];
  return self;
}
- (BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL) acceptsFirstMouse: (NSEvent*) pEvent {
    return YES;
}
- (void) viewDidMoveToWindow {
    NSWindow* pWindow = [self window];
    if (pWindow) {
        [pWindow makeFirstResponder: self];
        [pWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents: YES];
    }
}
- (void) drawRect: (NSRect) rect {
    
    NSLog(@"drawRect %f, %f, %f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width);
}
- (void) onTimer: (NSTimer*) pTimer {
    NSRect r;
    if (pTimer == mTimer) {
        //NSLog(@"mTimer");

    }
}
- (void) getMouseXY: (NSEvent*) pEvent x: (int*) pX y: (int*) pY {
    NSPoint pt = [pEvent locationInWindow];
    *pX = (int) pt.x;
    //*pY = mGraphics->Height() - (int) pt.y;
    *pY = 555 - (int) pt.y;
    NSLog(@"%f , %f", pt.x, pt.y);

}
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent*)event {
    NSLog(@"mouseDown called");
}
- (void) mouseUp: (NSEvent*) event {
    int x, y;
    [self getMouseXY:event x:&x y:&y];
}
- (void) mouseDragged: (NSEvent*) event {
    int x, y;
    [self getMouseXY:event x:&x y:&y];
}
- (void) rightMouseDown: (NSEvent*) event {
    int x, y;
    [self getMouseXY:event x:&x y:&y];
}
- (void) rightMouseUp: (NSEvent*) event {
    int x, y;
    [self getMouseXY:event x:&x y:&y];
}
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>) sender {
    NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    return (([pboard.types containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]) ? NSDragOperationLink : NSDragOperationNone);
}
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>) sender {
    NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType] ) {
        //NSPoint pt = [self convertPoint:[sender draggingLocation] fromView:nil];
        for (NSString *path in [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType]) {
            const char* tmp=[path UTF8String];
            NSLog(@"%@", path);
            //if (mGraphics)  {
                //mGraphics->OnMouseDrop(pt.x, mGraphics->Height() - pt.y, (char*)tmp);
                //break;
            //}
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification*)notification {
    //NSLog(@"Resize");
}
- (void)windowDidMiniaturize:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"Minimize");
}
- (void)windowDidDeMiniaturize:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"DeMinimize");
}
- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender {
  [NSApp terminate:sender];
  return YES;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  [NSApplication sharedApplication];
  [[[[Window alloc] init] autorelease] makeMainWindow];
  [NSApp run];
}
```

But drawRect() is not called at all, what is the problem?

Should this procedure be like Windows, is called when there are dirty areas that need to be redrawn?

Comment: Most methods aren't `NSWindow` methods. Where did you copy the code from?

Comment: drawRect() is usually called to draw into an NSView and that seems to be missing.

Comment: So, how do I complete my code with NSView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, how do I complete my code with NSView?

In lieu of working with your example I recommend something like the following for your consideration.  It is another way of creating a Cocoa app programmatically and demonstrates the use of -drawRect() in a custom NSView.  Note that the window is resizable similar to what you posted.  To run in Xcode first create an objc project, then delete the AppDelegate provided for you and paste the following into main.m after deleting the original code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface CustomView : NSView
//methods automatically called
@end

@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
 if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect]) != nil) {
  // Add initialization code here
 }
 return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
// **** Background **** //
[[NSColor orangeColor] set];
[NSBezierPath fillRect:rect];

NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:NSInsetRect([self bounds], 30,30)];
[[NSColor redColor] set];
[path fill];
[[NSColor whiteColor] set];
[path setLineWidth:1.0];
[path stroke];
}

//  Use this if you want 0,0 (origin) to be top, left //
//  Otherwise origin will be at bottom, left (Unflipped) //
-(BOOL)isFlipped {
 return YES;
}
@end

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
  NSWindow *window;
}
- (void) myBtnAction: (id)sender;
- (void) buildMenu;
- (void) buildWnd;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void) myBtnAction: (id)sender {
 NSBeep();
}

- (void) buildMenu {
NSMenu *menubar = [NSMenu new];
NSMenuItem *appMenuItem = [NSMenuItem new];
[menubar addItem:appMenuItem];
[NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
NSMenu *appMenu = [NSMenu new];
NSMenuItem *quitMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit"
        action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];
[appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
[appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
}

- (void) buildWnd {
#define _wndW 500
#define _wndH 450

window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH )styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO];
[window center];
[window setTitle: @"Custom View"];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];

// **** Create an instance of CustomView (NSView) **** //
CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 20, 80, _wndW - 40, _wndH - 100 )];
[view setAutoresizingMask: NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable ];
[[window contentView] addSubview:view];

// **** Button **** //
NSButton *myBtn =[[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 30, 30, 95, 30 )];
[myBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleRounded ];
[myBtn setTitle: @"Beep"];
[myBtn setAction: @selector (myBtnAction:)];
[[window contentView] addSubview: myBtn];

// **** Quit btn **** //
NSButton *quitBtn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 10, 40, 40 )];
[quitBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleCircular ];
[quitBtn setTitle: @"Q" ];
[quitBtn setAutoresizingMask: NSViewMinXMargin];
[quitBtn setAction:@selector(terminate:)];
[[window contentView] addSubview: quitBtn];
}

- (void) applicationWillFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
[self buildMenu];
[self buildWnd];
}

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
}
@end

int main() {
NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
[application setDelegate:appDelegate];
[application run];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works, I successfully implemented it on my code, thanks
I do not understand the difference between the AppDelegate method and the code given by me, seems to be no difference, the application works the same

Comment: Correct, you don't have to use an AppDelegate and could build the window in some other class (which is what your example does), but you'll note that Xcode adds an AppDelegate automatically as their preferred method.  However, there is more than one way to create an app.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question please. How to add a modal window without interface builder? ModalWindow *modalSheet = [[ModalWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 200) owner: self]; fail on me

Comment: NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
 //[alert setAlertStyle:NSAlertStyleCritical];
 [alert setMessageText:@"There was an error."];
 [alert setInformativeText:@"Please fix the code."];
 [alert runModal];

Comment: But on the alert cannot add elements like labels, textfields, buttons etc 

Need a modal window with elements and control functions

Comment: NSDocModalWindowMask is deprecated.  Might be able to use -runModalForWindow: .  Look in Xcode Documentation under NSApplication/Managing Windows, Panels, and Menus to learn more.   Probably should start a new thread if need more help with this problem.  I don't have any good examples already written.